# Show convergence of a sequence using $\varepsilon$-definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence

I would like to show that the sequence $\frac{4n^2+3n}{n^2-4n+4}$ converges to $4$ as $n \to \infty$ by using the $\varepsilon$-definition of convergence. I am aware that it would probably be easier to use certain limit laws to cancel out the $n$'s, but I am not sure that this is allowed at this point in the course.

Here is what I have done so far:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given.
$$ \left|\frac{4n^2+3n}{n^2-4n+4}-4\right| = \left|\frac{4n^2+3n-4(n^2-4n+4)}{n^2-4n+4}\right|
= \left|\frac{19n-16}{n^2-4n+4}\right|
= \frac{19n-16}{n^2-4n+4} < \varepsilon$$

Now I would like to solve this inequation for $n$, so that I can then argue that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the inequation holds for any $n \geq N$, but I am not sure how to actually go about doing this.

Comment: Take $n$ large. Then $$\frac{19n-16}{n^2-4n+4}  \leq \frac{19n}{n^2-4n} = \frac{19}{n-4}$$

Comment: @Andrew you actually don't need $n$ large for this. Increasing the numerator and decreasing the denominator are two ways to get a larger rational, so the first inequality still holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ where the rational is defined.

Comment: @StephenGoree well you need $n>3$ at least, so depends on your perspective.

Comment: @pancini Sure, but I assumed we were all on the same page that it went without saying, given the context of the problem and specific function, so I was speaking to the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful thing to keep in mind is that you can often simplify algebra greatly by just using bounds. For example, you have
$$\left|\frac{4n^2+3n}{n^2-4n+4}-4\right|=\left|\frac{19n-16}{(n-2)^2}\right|.$$

Now let's try to replace $19n-16$ with something nicer. For large enough $n$, $19n-16<20n-40=20(n-2)$, which would let us cancel one of the $n-2$ factors. Solving that inequality shows $19n-16<20n-40$ provided $n>24$. After this assumption we can simplify
$$\left|\frac{19n-16}{(n-2)^2}\right|<\left|\frac{20(n-2)}{(n-2)^2}\right|=\frac{20}{n-2}.$$
Now pick $N>24$ so that $n>N$ implies $\frac{20}{n-2}<\varepsilon$; I'll let you take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to lead you right up to the answer without directly giving you the answer, but I'll give you the key intuition that's going to make this all make sense: substitution.

We can pretty quickly factor the denominator to get $(n-2)^2$, so now let's rewrite that last expression before the "$<\varepsilon$" using $k=n-2$.

$$\frac{19n-16}{(n-2)^2}=\frac{19(k+2)-16}{k^2}=\frac{19k+12}{k^2}$$

Now can you see the last couple steps to show this limit is $0$?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{4n^2+3n}{n^2-4n+4} = \frac{4(n-2)^2 - 16 + 19n}{(n-2)^2} = \frac{19}{n-2} + \frac{22}{(n-2)^2} + 4.
$$
Now
$|\frac{19}{n-2} + \frac{22}{(n-2)^2} + 4-4|<\varepsilon.$

Or, if the partial fraction is not obvious:
$$
|\frac{4n^2+3n}{n^2-4n+4}-4| = |4\frac{n^2-(n^2-4n+4)}{(n-2)^2} + 3\frac{n}{(n-2)^2}|=|4\frac{4n-4}{(n-2)^2} + 3\frac{n}{(n-2)^2}|<\varepsilon.
$$